# Firestore Database model create with kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I'm trying to model a database schema for Firestore. How can I create this database model?

**This is my recipe data class**

```
data class Foods(
var foodId:String?,
var foodName:String,
var foodCategory:String,
var foodCalory:Int,
var foodIngredients:String,
var foodRecipe:String,
var foodCookingTime:Int,
var foodImg:String?)
```

**My Users Id getting this**

```
  val user : FirebaseUser? = auth?.currentUser
    val userID: String = user?.uid.toString()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see in your screenshot, your document (vp0q ...) holds an array of `Foods` objects. If you want to be able to map that document to an object of a particular class, you should consider using the following class declarations:

```
data class User (recipe: Array<Foods>)
```

Now, to read that document, you should use the following reference:

```
val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid
val rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
val usersRef = rootRef.collection("users")
usersRef.document(uid).get()
    .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
        if (document != null) {
            val recipe = document.toObject<Foods>().recipe
            //Do what you need to do with your recipe array
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "No such document")
        }
    }
    .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
        Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", exception)
    }
```

Comment: Hi @AlexMamo , thank you very much for your reply. But I asked how I can create this database model. I designed the model in this picture by hand to be an example in Firestore.

Comment: @Ayse.S I am having trouble understanding what you are trying to achieve, could you please edit OP and be more specific about it?

Comment: To achieve that database structure, you should use the `User` class that exists in my answer. Have tried it?

Comment: Hi @AlexMamo  yes alex your answer was very helpful for me. thank you

Comment: Good to hear that, Ayse.S.